# build 5col 2row table

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to build an html table with 2 rows and 5 columns?

Comment: Jage's answer is the best you're likely to get without more details of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice dynamic way of doing it.

```
function createTable(columns, rows) {
  var table = $("<table></table>");
  var row;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
    row = $("<tr></tr>");
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j ++) {
      row.append($("<td></td>"));
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
  return table;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(body).append(createTable(5,2));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With html:

```
$('<table> <!-- more html here --> </table>').appendTo(document.body);
```